# JAVA : parse int method while using it in JTextField not working

Tags: user-interface, jtextfield, parseint

I made a simple code to calculate BMI but it shows error in the line with the parseInt method can anyone help (a bit new to java :P)

```
  public BmiF(){
super("BMI Calculator");
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
t1 = new JTextField("enter wieght in kg",10);
final int num1 =Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
add(t1);
t2 = new JTextField("enter hieght in m",10);
final int num2 =Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
add(t2);
t3 = new JTextField("",10);
t3.setEditable(false);
add(t3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
b = new JButton("Claculate BMI");
add(b);
b.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            int k = num1/(num2*num2);
                t3.setText(String.format("Your BMI is %d",k));
                }
            }
        );
}
```

}

Comment: on which line is the error, and what is the error message

Comment: @user3779888 Put final int num2 =Integer.parseInt(t2.getText()); inside the actionPerformed loop. Its trying to parse it straight away before any input is entered. Also you have to put final int num1 =Integer.parseInt(t1.getText()); in there aswell

Comment: any progress with the application?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse the `String` "enter weight in kg" as `int`. See java doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for what your initialization means.

You need to parse the string in the `ActionListener` and add a [`catch` exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) rule.

I've gotten the bellow code to work. Another problem you have is that you need to declare the `int` or `double` in the `try` block of code *without* the `final` qualifier, so that you can change the variable after initialization

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

textArea.setEditable(true);
textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 15));

button = new JButton("ok");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            String string = textArea.getText().trim();
            int weight = Integer.parseInt(string);

            //do stuff with weight variable

            System.out.println(weight);
        } catch(Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("number exception");
        }

    }
});

frame.add(textField);
frame.add(textArea);
frame.add(button);
frame.setSize(300, 100);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: hey thanks alot actually i didn't think smone will answer so quickly :p

Comment: hey sorry but it still isnt working except this time i used a parseDouble method and used try catch and also put the required code inside action performed

Comment: I put some code that worked just fine for me. You should change it to your needs, seeing that I haven't inherited `JFrame` in my project and only checked what was going wrong for you.

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: you're welcome, you should mark the response as accepted so others who have the same problem can relate to it